# Framework7 and map

Tags: dictionary, html-framework-7

Thank you in advance for your help..
Here’s the problem :

I use the Framework7 and it works well but…

On the 3rd tab on the bottom (« se repérer », locate) a map could load, but the system bug…
The complete map ( every tiles) load ONLY if we resize the window, it’s ok on the computer, but impossible to do on a smartphone. 
I think I missed somthing, but I dont find. 
I guess the map dont initialize correctly when the 3rd screen is loading, but I didn’t find how to do. 
If I put the map on the main page : everything works well. 
Thank’s to the personn which will find. 
Best regards,

The example is available on http://weblol.free.fr

Comment: Add some code example here. How you init the map?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use a callback to call resize function (if there is any for leaflet)

you could also use a better map framework